# Which process is periodically writing to the disk?

Tags: snow-leopard, hard-drive

Even when I am not doing anything on my Mac, I see a lot of Disk IO: "Data Written per Sec" in Activity Monitor showns continuous writes:

[image: Disk Activity]

Is this normal? Why would some process continuously write? I understand there can be some housekeeping activities going on, the "Sleep image" being updated, but does this happen this frequently? (I have not set up Time Machine)

Edit: I have quite some free memory:

[image: Memory Usage]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what's running under My Processes in Activity Monitor?

Comment: Now (when I am back home from work) I see that the activity has come down (peak is around 900 KB/s). What was open in the morning is open now: Twitter App, Chrome and text edit (no changes made there. I typed something 4 days ago that I want to remember, but too lazy to save, and to think where to save)

Comment: Will post a screenshot when I see a similar scenario. If I dont, will close this Q.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a better idea what's causing the activity with some of OS X's command-line tools:

`sudo iotop` -- display of what processes are doing the most I/O, updated every 5 secs.

`sudo iosnoop` -- shows I/O as it happens, including the process ID and process name doing the I/O, as well as data size, file path, etc

In both cases, you'll need to authenticate as an admin to run them, and use Control-C to exit.  They may not tell you precisely why the activity's happening, but they'll at least tell you what processes and files are involved, which usually narrows it down considerably.

Comment: Can someone pretty please write a GUI for these use-cases :D

Answer (score 9):

In addition to `iotop` and `iosnoop` you may use `fs_usage`.

```
sudo fs_usage -w -f filesys -e grep  | grep -i ' write '
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I would love it if you edited the highest scoring answer once you have the reputation to add this - it makes that answer much more complete.

Answer (score 1):

A few things: (Written in bullet points to make it concise)

- The OS itself writes.
- Open applications write.
- Browsers write as well, in the case of cookies, and when your RAM is maxed out.

Comment: Yes, I understand these. But how frequently? I have a lot of free RAM: Now around 5GB (added this detail to question as well)

Comment: Every second the computer is on. Computers always write to disk all the time.

Comment: mega bytes every second?

Comment: Depends on what OS you're using, what applications are open, ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use `lsof` to check what processes are writing to the disk. [Here's](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) the man page for it.

Comment: `lsof` is a 'snapshot' based utility that shows everything going on within a few seconds time. IF you don't run it at the precise moment that the I/O is taking place, you'll miss it. OS X's utilities (`iotop` and `iosnoop` and numerous other users have answered with) are live/refreshing and very customizable utilities that I (IMO/personally) vastly prefer.