# Why is Outlook 2011 constantly writing to my hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, ms-office

I recently installed a hard disk write monitoring program (MenuMeters), and for some reason it was reporting that my drive is *constantly* being written to. By closing programs one at a time, I've discovered that this is caused by Outlook 2011, but I have no idea why.

I have to keep Outlook running all the time, for work, but I'd really like to stop this constant disk writing, if possible, since I'm afraid that it's impacting my MacBook Pro's performance.

I read about some ways to more closely monitor my disk activity on [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23812/which-process-is-periodically-writing-to-the-disk), so I tred using `sudo iotop`. It revealed that something called 'Microsoft Datab' is the culprit for all these writes while Outlook is open.

Anyone have any ideas on how (if?) I can stop the constant disk writes while keeping Outlook open?

Comment: Your 'Microsoft Datab' is cut off (because top likes to do that; it's not your fault) - the full name is "Microsoft Database Daemon".

Comment: Have you installed all of the service packs yet?  I had tons of issues before the service pack.

Comment: @BillBrasky I've keep up to date as best I could, though I'm not sure if Microsoft makes updates available through the usual Apple->Software Updates... menu. Is there somewhere else I should be looking for updates?

Comment: Start one of the apps and use Help->Check For Updates.  I just got update 14.2.3 today.

Comment: @BillBrasky That worked! I didn't realize that my auto-update had been turned off, and I was using v14.1.3. Updating to 14.2.3 got rid of the constant writes! Feel free to add your suggestion as an actual answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed all of the service packs yet? I had tons of issues before the service pack.

Start one of the apps and use Help->Check For Updates. I just got update 14.2.3 today.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the Database Utility that comes with Office to resolve any database corruptions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Database Utility app. I ran the "Rebuild" function, but unfortunately it didn't stops the constant disk writes.

Comment: :( hmm ask Microsoft?